# Site Collection Administrator list for 2010 On-premise site collection

Tags: powershell

I want to get the list of all site collection administrators for a 2010 On-premise site collection using Powershell.

Please suggest how to perform the same.

Thanks,
Kanika

Answer (score 0):

```
$site = Get-SPSite "URL"
$site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators
```